# writing tab-limited excel with utf8

Tags: java, excel, utf-8, byte-order-mark, csv

I want to write tab-delimited utf8 excel file.
My PrintWriter looks like this:

```
Charset utf8Charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, utf8Charset);
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(osw, BUFFER_SIZE));
```

So it seems like it must write symbols in utf8.
But when I open xls I shows some invalid characters:

[image]

Seems like it is a UTF8 issue. So I decided to add UTF8 BOM to the file before writing any information. And then excel showed me this:

[image]

But what is interesting - when I used the same approach (with adding UTF8 BOM) for writing CSV files (using "," delimiter) it worked well.
I would appreciate any help, thanks!

EDIT:
I've reproduced the bug but with defferent information within the report (different column names). Anyway here is what hex showes me

file with UTF8 BOM:

[image]

and the same file without UTF8 BOM:

[image]

seems like after adding UTF8 BOM excel just starts to ignore tab-delimiters. I still dont know what to do.

Comment: Can you upload those two CSV files to the net? Also what program are you using to open them?

Comment: Have you tried opening resulting files in hex editor and check output?

Comment: @LS_dev I've just attached the pictures with hex.